# Using Private Framework: Importing RadioPreferences.h

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, private-functions

I'm following the selected answer [importing private frameworks in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206133/importing-private-frameworks-in-xcode?rq=1)

Basically I want to be able to control Airplane mode in my app. When I import `RadioPreferences.h` into my app and try to compile, I'm getting `Expected Identifier` for `@class <RadiosPreferencesDelegate>;`

I'm not exactly sure what to do next. I didn't even know you can forward declare protocols.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095109/reachability-airplane-mode-3g-vs-wifi

Comment: I'm getting:
`Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RadiosPreferences", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in NetworkManager.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: Where did you find `RadioPreferences.h`, you need to make sure you link against the correct framework?

Comment: ACB's answer shows that I should paste the contents into `RadiosPreferences.h`. I'm assuming that's the AppSupport.framework?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First copy the following contents into a file named `RadioPreferences.h`. (Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/13095362/418715 ).

```
@protocol RadiosPreferencesDelegate
-(void)airplaneModeChanged;
@end


@interface RadiosPreferences : NSObject
{
    struct __SCPreferences *_prefs;
    int _applySkipCount;
    id <RadiosPreferencesDelegate> _delegate;
    BOOL _isCachedAirplaneModeValid;
    BOOL _cachedAirplaneMode;
    BOOL notifyForExternalChangeOnly;
}

- (id)init;
- (void)dealloc;
@property(nonatomic) BOOL airplaneMode;
- (void)refresh;
- (void)initializeSCPrefs:(id)arg1;
- (void)notifyTarget:(unsigned int)arg1;
- (void)synchronize;
- (void *)getValueForKey:(id)arg1;
- (void)setValue:(void *)arg1 forKey:(id)arg2;
@property(nonatomic) BOOL notifyForExternalChangeOnly; // @synthesize notifyForExternalChangeOnly;
@property(nonatomic) id <RadiosPreferencesDelegate> delegate; // @synthesize delegate=_delegate;

@end
```

---

- Next, go to the *Build Phases* of your target in Xcode and expand the *Link Binary With Libraries* section.
- In a finder window navigate to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks`. Replace `iPhoneOS6.0.sdk` in the path with the sdk you are targeting.
- Drag AppSupport.framework over to your expanded *Link Binary With Libraries* section.

Everything should now compile and you will be able to use the class.

Comment: Actually wait, I'm still getting `Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RadiosPreferences", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in NetworkManager.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)` after following this.

Comment: The above code is working for me with entitlements for <= 6.x. But I am  unable to toggle it for IOS 7.x. Please give the Api details if you are able to do it

Comment: @Ninja I am facing the same error. How you resolved Undefined symbols for architecture armv7?

Comment: sorry, i don't remember. this was a long time ago.