# Correct way to use a private library in objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I downloaded a collection of private libraries from [this link](https://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks). When I click download I get all frameworks. So these are only header files not the .framework files that are available in Xcode. So I linked them by the usual method of going to build phases, in it I go to link binary with libraries click on + and choose the header files from a framework (preferences framework in my case). After these files are added to my project I try to make an object from one of the libraries and try to call their instance methods. When I try to execute this program I get this error. I get this whether I run it on the device or simulator.

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DevicePINController", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in UAViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
>   (use -v to see invocation)

DevicePinController is a part of a private framework preferences.h.I am trying to make an object of it UA

**EDIT:** I tried using other framework headers such as bluetooth and I get this error in all.

**EDIT:** I tried adding the entire framework to the project instead of adding individual header files.Now the error is

d: framework not found BluetoothManager
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to actually build the framework. You can't just link against a header file; that doesn't make sense.

Try adding all the .m files in the Preferences folder as **Compile Sources**, and remove the header file from **Link Binary with Libraries**.

**Added:** I realize now this answer is incorrect. The files OP is trying to use are not a library, but header files from Apple's private frameworks. Here's a related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13388225/893113

Comment: There are no .m files in any folder(frameworks).There are only header files in all of the folders

Comment: You can click on my given link and see for yourself.This error has wasted my so many days

Comment: @losBoy are there no `.a` files?