# Open Siri using private API's in iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8, iphone-privateapi, siri, springboard

I want to make an app that **won't** be released on the App Store. I want this app to open siri through private API's, basically inject a home button press and hold into the events queue. I have tried using `GSEvent`([GSSendEvent - Inject Touch Event iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16160589/gssendevent-inject-touch-event-ios)), but it no longer works(it silently fails) after iOS 7. I believe it is possible through `SBUIController` but I can't figure how to use `SBUIController` in iOS 8. To be clear, I want to do this on a **non-jailbroken** phone.

How can I go about doing this in iOS 8?

Thanks

Comment: It might be helpful to include the code that you tried (but fails after iOS 7).

Comment: The code that I tried is in the SO answer linked...it is a known behavior not specific to any code that fails after iOS 7

Comment: Keep in mind that in APIs, Apple may refer to "Siri" as the "VirtualAssistant".  This may help you find what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check out the runtime headers of all the private/public apis [here](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers).

I found a method hidden in accessibility, which could possibly work in your case. Have a look at it here: http://git.io/frK6Sw . The method is named `-(void)openSiri`, which suggest that it might open Siri, I haven't tried though.

Comment: I've seen that before! However, i cant understand how to use the runtime headers...I've tried the example in the readme and it doesn't work. Can you please provide an example? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, have a look at this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/13388225/1001803 . You have to copy the private framework and then add the headers yourself (or just write one, where the method names you need are the same). Afterwards you should be able to use it. Btw. if you turn on assistive touch in accessibility, you can see it has a button "open siri", so that means there must be a method which opens siri somewhere in accesibility :) You could probably reverse engineer that, however that could be a little more difficult.

Comment: @DominikHadl - I can understand the open siri part. How do you inject home button? Any example on that?